# What is the namespace for Mapper.Map in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, mapper

I am working on ASP.NET MVC4 and i want to map my view model and database table object.
And for that i want to use Mapper.Map.But i don't have any idea about its Namespace.

Can anyone suggest me the namespace for that ?

Answer (score 3):

That's not a namespace from MVC 4 directly.  It's a namespace that belongs to [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/).